# How to add timer in local push notification?

Tags: timer, push-notification

I want to add a timer in local push notification which will update after every second, so that user shall able to track down the time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

10 second later call function

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 10 ) {
   userNotification()
}
```

Comment: this is the code which will put delay in calling function. I needed timer in notification and i came to know that is not possible at all.

Comment: func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 10 ) {
   userNotification()
}
  
    }
// "Appdelegate try please"