# Countdown in iOS UserNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, unusernotificationcenter

I want to show a countdown (which updates every second) in an iOS UserNotification.
I cannot believe that it is not possible like it seems to be on [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162908/how-to-show-a-timer-on-a-notification):

I found [this old question with an unsatisfying answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707209/how-to-add-timer-in-local-push-notification).

Please tell me, if it is even possible and if so "HOW?". Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: f Apple
Thanks for the answer though